# Google gmail api delegation issues

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-api-php-client, delegation

I'm running php code with the google API such that one account (account1@example.com) can access mails from another account (account2@example.com). I have logged into account2 and added account1 as delegate. I confirmed that from account1 I can access the mails from account2.

Now, when I run the following code I get an error which I posted below. To confirm that the code (most likely?) is not the true issue, I set both email addresses to account1@ and the issue was not at hand, I could get all emails.

```
$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
);
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName("Yeti user control");
$gClient->setAuthConfig($GOOGLE_AUTH);
$gClient->setScopes($scopes);
$gClient->setSubject("account1@example.com");
$gService = new Google_Service_Directory($gClient);

$users = $gService->users->listUsers(array("domain" => "example.com"));

$gGmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($gClient);
$messages = $gGmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('account2@example.com');
print_r($messages);
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Delegation denied for account1@example.com", "errors": [ { "message": "Delegation denied for account1@example.com", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

Now, how come that when my account actually has been allowed as a delegate, it gets this delegation denied error message from the API?

The full error stack trace:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(181): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(779): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array) #4 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(232): Google_Client->execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #5 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\site_tools\site_tools_files\GoogleAPI\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Gmail\Resource\UsersMessages.php(166): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #6
```

google class:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: Are the emails `account1@example.com` & `account2@example.com` hosted under Google Workspace?

Comment: Yes, both on the same workspace

Comment: I see, upon checking on this official [Gmail API article](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), `"Google Workspace organizations can use the Delegates resource to manage the delegates of accounts in their organization. This requires use of a service account that has been delegated domain-wide authority."` Have you done delegating the domain-wide authority to a service account already? If not yet, you can review this [Google article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)